# Validating textbox inside a div JQUERY

Tags: jquery, html

I have 5 textbox in a Div, the div and textbox are dynamically created using jquery, I need to validate the textbox if has value or null, IF one of the textbox inside the div is NULL an error message will display in a span, the SPAN tag is also place inside the div. The textbox also turn red when it is null, that part works, but the message error has the problem. Any idea?

THIS IS THE HTML

```
 <div id="QuestionTBDiv1" >
    <label>Question</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="quiztxtBox[]" size="57" id="quiztxtBox[]" placeholder="Question #1"><br/>
    <label>Answer</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="quiztxtBox[]" size="24" id="answer[]" placeholder="Choice A">&nbsp;<input type="radio" class = "choiceA" name="correct_answer1" value="A">&nbsp;<input type="text" name="quiztxtBox[]" size="24" id="answer[]" placeholder="Choice B">&nbsp;<input type="radio" class = "choiceB" name="correct_answer1" value="B"><br/><input type="text" name="quiztxtBox[]" size="24" id="answer[]" placeholder="Choice C">&nbsp;<input type="radio" class = "choiceC" name="correct_answer1" value="C">&nbsp;<input type="text" name="quiztxtBox[]" size="24" id="answer[]" placeholder="Choice D">&nbsp;<input type="radio" class = "choiceD" name="correct_answer1" value="D"><br><span name="errMchoice" class="errorMsg"></span>
        </div>
```

THIS IS THE JQUERY

```
 $("[name='quiztxtBox[]']").each(function(){
          if ($(this).empty()) {

            $(this).css({"background-color":"#f6d9d4"});
            $( "div span:last-child" ).html("This is error message.");
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) method removes the children(*childNodes*) of the selected elements, it doesn't check the length of the `value` property. As it returns a jQuery object and not a *boolean* value and in JavaScript an object is a truthy value your condition is always `true`, you should check the length of the value.

Also note that `$( "div span:last-child" )` selects all the `div span:last-child` elements in the document. You can use the `.siblings()` method for selecting the target elements.

```
if ( !this.value.length )
   // selecting the sibling `span` for showing the message 
   $(this).css(...).siblings('span.errorMsg').text('Read the docs!');
```

Comment: Hi, I stated that the div with textbox is dynamically created, You used class so all the existing span with that class displays the error.

Comment: @user2901740 Hi, have you tried it? _"so all the existing span with that class displays the error"_ No, it doesn't do this.

Comment: Yes it did not work, I found the problem, I have another validation for radio buttons, I think it is the one that conflicts with the codes that why it is not working.. :) I tried to removed the validation and it works, I just need to find ways to include validation for radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

> $( "div span:last-child" ).html("This is error message.");

I suppose this should be

> `$( "div span" ).text("This is error message.");`

or

> `$( "div:last-child" ).text("This is error message.");`

since span is the last child of `div` and the only `span` element next to `div`. And also, `.text` since the value you set is not an HTML content but a text content. Hope this helps!